# Unable to create migration plan because of XXXX: unknown migration in database

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlmigrations

I'm using the migration package `github.com/rubenv/sql-migrate`. I had my migration files (a bunch of .sql files) in `migrationFilesBaseDir`. The function `DoMigrations` contains my migration logic like so:

```
func DoMigrations(dsn, migrationFilesBaseDir string) {

    m := migration{
        dsn:                   dsn,
        migrationFilesBaseDir: migrationFilesBaseDir,
    }
    driver, err := sql.Open("postgres", m.dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    m.driver = driver

    tableExists, err := m.checkMigratedFilesTableExists()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if tableExists {
        if err := m.runNewlyAddedMigrations(); err != nil {
            if err == errNoNewlyAddedMigrationFile {
                return
            }           
            panic(err)
        }
    } else {
        if _, err := m.runInitialMigration(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

What DoMigrations() does simply is

1. check that migrated_files table exists in db
2. if table doesn't exist (i.e., no migration has ever been performed on current db) then `runInitialMigration` else `runNewlyAddedMigrations`.

Basically, `runInitialMigration` creates a `migrated_files` table that records migrated file names.
I had to make a modification (seed entries) in one of the db tables, so I wrote a new migration (`.sql`) file inside `migrationFilesBaseDir`, run `DoMigrations()` again, which then runNewlyAddedMigrations.
runNewlyAddedMigrations checks the file names found in `migrationFilesBaseDir` against entries of `migrated_files` table to detect newly added `.sql` files. At the point of applying content of the newly added file to the database, the program panics with error  `Unable to create migration plan because of XXXX: unknown migration in database`.

How can I solve this, please?

Comment: sql-migrate maintains its own record of applied migrations in a table named gorp_migrations, so you don't need migrated_files. The error you got occurs if you rename or delete existing migrations. Update gorp_migrations to reflect your changes.

Comment: Yeah, I later found out (through pgAdmin) about the `gorp_migrations` table too after I was done writing `DoMigrations()`. I think I must mention that `runInitialMigration()` uses `migrate.FileMigrationSource` and `runNewlyAddedMigrations()` uses `&migrate.MemoryMigrationSource`. 
Now, I just call `migrate.FileMigrationSource` every time a new migration file is added to the `migrationFilesBaseDir` and the package `sql-migrate` handles the rest.

Answer (score 3):

The error means that you have migrations referenced in your database table (default name is `gorp_migrations`) but not in your local migrations folder.

This can happend becouase:

- you created and applied a migration in a specific branch.
- applied a migration a then removed the file.

To solve it just go to the db table that stores the migrations, look in the table for the migration and remove it.